# set proxy for windows subsystem for android apps

Tags: http-proxy, windows-subsystem-for-android

I have installed Windows subsystem for android in windows 11 and installed some android apps.
I want to know how to set proxy server for android apps running by WSA?

Answer (score 5):

You can set the proxy over adb. You need to have Developer Options enabled in WSA Settings.

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy 192.168.xx.xxx:8080
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Julian. It works.

use following command to remove proxy:

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy :0
```